# How to skip items in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries(over a thousand) from an API response that I reordered based on some other logic. Each list of dict's has an ID. My goal is to update the ID to start at 0 again and increment 1 for each list.
Here is an example of what I have:

```
list_of_dicts = [
 {
  'id':   5,
  'age': 22,
  'name': 'Bryan'
 },
 {
  'id':   0,
  'age': 28,
  'name': 'Zach'
 },
]
```

And what I need:

```
list_of_dicts = [
 {
  'id':   0,
  'age': 22,
  'name': 'Bryan'
 },
 {
  'id':   1,
  'age': 28,
  'name': 'Zach'
 },
]
```

Below is my current code. I keep getting an error of *'int' object has no attribute 'update'* or a str error, probably because it's iterating past `id`.

`Combined` holds my list of dictionaries.

```
    counter = 0
    for i in combined:
        for k,v in i.items():
            if k == 'id':
                v.update({'id': counter})
                counter += 1
            else:
                continue
```

Can someone guide me on where I'm going wrong at?

Comment: To clarify, is your structure exactly as you have shown or is the outer object a `list`? What you show is not valid syntax.

Comment: [`update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=update#dict.update) is a dictionary function. `v` is not a dictionary. `i` is.

Comment: Nope exactly as shown @Axe319 and ahh okay, definitely clears up that part of it

Comment: You can't have `{}` around a list of dictionaries, it should be `list_of_dicts = [...]`

Comment: sorry - i just looked at my API response again. it is in [...]. Updating my original post now.

Comment: Thank you all for the help - you always get me unblocked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop to update the `id` element of the dictionary. Just index it directly.

```
for i, d in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
    d['id'] = i
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar !

Comment: Stackoverflow is still making me wait "4 minutes" before I accept it as answer. @Johnny Mopp

Answer (score -1):

If you have a list of dicts then you could iterate over list enumerating and change the ids:

```
for i,di in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
     di['id'] = i
```

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension if you don't use the result.

Comment: okey, thanks! can I ask why?

Comment: Because it's silly. Why make a new list if you don't need it?

Comment: Well first of all, it won't work. `di['id'] = i` is an assignment statement, not a value or expression.

Comment: That, too. You could do it with `:=` instead of `=`.

Comment: @Barmar Doesn't `:=` only accept simple identifiers as targets?

Comment: oh that's right thank you all

Comment: nope the := doesn't work either! I've tryed now